# No Eclipse como adiciono as Packages para ser importadas depois e usa-las?

Tags: eclipse

Sou iniciante em desenvolvimento com o eclipse e java gostaria de saber como faço para adicionar várias Packages para que eu possa seguir alguns exemplos e usa las? Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Botão direito do mouse em cima do seu projeto > New > Other > Pesquise por package > Selecione Package e clique em Next > Coloque o nome do pacote, exemplo: br.com.exemplo.package. Clique em Finish.

Seria isso? Espero que tenha ajudado.